# how to build a pluggable java application?

Tags: java, pluggable

How can I write a pluggable java application. I read about OSGI and some other plugin frameworks but I want to do that me myself.
Is there any easy way to write what I want?

Comment: yes, but it depends on what you requirements are.  You can add a jar to the class path at runtime and load a class from that new jar via reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can write your own plugins framework with some reflection. This link might be helpful. [Creating Extensible Applications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html)